# Remap input matrix into matrix with narrower range

Tags: c++, c++17

When writing image processing/computer vision algorithms, I usually use `double` in computations and then I have to remap the values back into `std::uint8_t` range, because that is what PNG supports. The main problem is that the image is represented as multi channel entries in a matrix, and remapping should be done for each channel individually. Here is the formula I used for the remapping:

\$srcrange=srcmax-srcmin+1 \\
dstrange=dstmax-dstmin+1 \\
mapped=dstmin + \frac{value - srcmin}{srcrange}*dstrange
\$

\$srcmax,srcmin\$ are computed for each channel individually.

The code will work when remapping to wider range, but then `dst_min` and `dst_max` values should be manually specified, otherwise overflow is guaranteed. It is a use case I am supporting.

### code

```
// remap larger range into smaller one
template <typename U, typename MT, bool SO>
auto remap_to_channeled(const blaze::DenseMatrix<MT, SO>& source,
                        U dst_min = std::numeric_limits<U>::min(),
                        U dst_max = std::numeric_limits<U>::max())
{
    using source_vector_type = blaze::UnderlyingElement_t<MT>;
    constexpr auto vector_size = source_vector_type::size();
    using element_type = blaze::UnderlyingElement_t<source_vector_type>;
    static_assert(blaze::IsStatic_v<source_vector_type> &&
                  blaze::IsDenseVector_v<source_vector_type>);
    auto min_reducer = [](source_vector_type prev, const source_vector_type& current) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < prev.size(); ++i) {
            if (prev[i] > current[i]) {
                prev[i] = current[i];
            }
        }

        return prev;
    };
    auto src_min_elems = blaze::reduce(source, min_reducer);

    auto max_reducer = [](source_vector_type prev, const source_vector_type& current) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < prev.size(); ++i) {
            if (prev[i] < current[i]) {
                prev[i] = current[i];
            }
        }

        return prev;
    };
    auto src_max_elems = blaze::reduce(source, max_reducer);

    using result_vector_type = blaze::StaticVector<U, source_vector_type::size()>;

    // pick according to std::common_type rules to make
    // more resistant to overflow/underflow and accuracy loss
    using proxy_type = std::common_type_t<element_type, U>;
    using proxy_vector = blaze::StaticVector<proxy_type, source_vector_type::size()>;

    result_vector_type dst_min_elems;
    std::fill(dst_min_elems.begin(), dst_min_elems.end(), dst_min);
    result_vector_type dst_max_elems;
    std::fill(dst_max_elems.begin(), dst_max_elems.end(), dst_max);

    proxy_vector src_range_length = src_max_elems - src_min_elems + 1;
    proxy_vector dst_range_length = dst_max_elems - dst_min_elems + 1;

    return blaze::evaluate(blaze::map(
        (~source),
        [src_min_elems, dst_min_elems, src_range_length, dst_range_length, vector_size](
            const source_vector_type& elem) {
            result_vector_type result{};
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vector_size; ++i) {
                result[i] = dst_min_elems[i] +
                            (static_cast<double>(elem[i] -
                                                 src_min_elems[i]) / // cast to double to make more
                                                                     // resistant to accuracy loss
                             src_range_length[i] *
                             dst_range_length[i]);
            }

            return result;
        }));
}
```

### Tests

```
TEST_CASE("test remap_to_channeled - simple case")
{
    blaze::StaticVector<int, 3> default_vector({0, 1, 2});
    blaze::DynamicMatrix<blaze::StaticVector<int, 3>> matrix(2, 3, default_vector);

    blaze::DynamicMatrix<blaze::StaticVector<std::uint8_t, 3>> expected(2, 3, {0, 0, 0});
    auto result = flash::remap_to_channeled<std::uint8_t>(matrix);
    REQUIRE(expected == result);
}

TEST_CASE("test remap_to_channeled - slightly harder case")
{
    blaze::StaticVector<int, 3> default_vector({0, 1, 2});
    blaze::DynamicMatrix<blaze::StaticVector<int, 3>> matrix(2, 3, default_vector);

    blaze::DynamicMatrix<blaze::StaticVector<std::uint8_t, 3>> expected(2, 3, {10, 10, 10});
    auto result = flash::remap_to_channeled<std::uint8_t>(matrix, 10, 12);
    REQUIRE(expected == result);
}

TEST_CASE("test remap_to_channeled - linear case")
{
    // input range is from 0 to 15, so the length of the range is 16
    // the output range is from 0 to 255, so the length is 256
    // for every value in input, remapped value should be value * 16

    blaze::DynamicMatrix<blaze::StaticVector<int, 3>> matrix(2, 8, {0, 0, 0});
    int multiplier = 16;
    int counter = 0;
    blaze::DynamicMatrix<blaze::StaticVector<std::uint8_t, 3>> expected(2, 8, {0, 0, 0});

    for (unsigned int counter = 0; counter < 16; ++counter) {
        auto i = counter / 8;
        auto j = counter % 8;

        matrix(i, j)[0] = counter;
        expected(i, j)[0] = counter * multiplier;
    }

    auto result = flash::remap_to_channeled<std::uint8_t>(matrix);
    REQUIRE(result == expected);
}
```

The full source code can be found [here](https://github.com/simmplecoder/blazing-gil).